# How to delete the first row of a PySpark DataFrame

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I would like to delete the first row of a PySpark DataFrame. For example, I have a DataFrame `df`.

```py
df.show()

+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|   z1|   a1|
|   z1|   b2|
|   z1|   c3|
|   x1|   a1|
|   x1|   b2|
|   x1|   c3|
+-----+-----+
```

and I would like to just have the following:

```py
+-----+-----+
| col1| col2|
+-----+-----+
|   z1|   b2|
|   z1|   c3|
|   x1|   a1|
|   x1|   b2|
|   x1|   c3|
+-----+-----+
```

How can this be done?

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Spark dataframes are unordered. Without an index/ordering column, the "first" row is not well-defined.

Comment: You don't delete rows from dataframes, they are immutable. You would need to build a query to exclude whatever rows you don't want.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451815/remove-first-row-from-pyspark-dataframe) solution works for me