# remove first row from pyspark dataframe

Tags: pyspark, filter, row, parquet

Just a general question. Does anybody know how to remove the entire first row of a pyspark dataframe.
I have tried using the following code, but that leaves my dataframe parquet output empty:

```
updated_bulk=bulk_spark_df.filter
(merged_mas_bulk_spark_df.'Number!='part=')
```

Number is a column and part is a data occurance in the first row

Comment: `updated_bulk = bulk_spark_df.filter("Number != 'part='")`

Comment: How do you determine what the first row is? Is the dataframe ordered by a particular column?

Comment: I don't think I  have been complete in phrasing my question.What it basically does is that it copies the first row(considered row from pandas perspective) when converting to a parquet file. When opening in apache parquet I hence view the first 'row' below the columns.

Answer (score 5):

With the following Dataframe.

```
df.show()
+---+----+---+
| ID|NAME|AGE|
+---+----+---+
|  1|John| 50|
|  2|Anna| 32|
|  3|Josh| 41|
|  4|Paul| 98|
+---+----+---+
```

You could do remove the first row like this.

```
df2 = spark.createDataFrame(df.tail(df.count()-1), df.schema)

df2.show()
+---+----+---+
| ID|NAME|AGE|
+---+----+---+
|  2|Anna| 32|
|  3|Josh| 41|
|  4|Paul| 98|
+---+----+---+
```