# Slice "entire" rows in Spark Dataframe [without pandas, without rdds, without monotonically increasing id, without skipRows]

Tags: dataframe, csv, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

A spark dataframe having this data:

| _c1 | _c2 | _c3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Null | Null | Null |
| file information | Null | Null |
| Null | Null | Null |
| real_column_name1 | real_column_name2 | real_column_name3 |
| a1 | a2 | a3 |
| b1 | b2 | b3 |
| c1 | c2 | c3 |

How do I write the logic wherein:

1. First 3 initial rows are removed [if there is some file information in any of the fields as shown in 2nd row 1st column so thereby unable to use isNull for this].
2. Make the 4th row as header, and then have only the next remaining data in the dataframe.

The issues with some previous posts, and YouTube videos:

1. Removing the whole rows.

   - Not based on a particular column field condition but removing the entire row.
2. Without using pandas.

   - Is pandas recommended if there's huge data?
3. skipRows.

   - Few videos are shown with skipRows option while loading in databricks, but that doesn't seem to be working if tried otherwise.
4. monotonically increasing id.

   - Not intended for generating consecutive values.
5. rdd.zipWithIndex().

   - As working with rdds, sparkContext isn't recommended for optimization ?

Any recommendations ?

Answer (score 0):

Apache Spark is fundamentally not row-based as `PySpark DataFrames` are partitioned on one or more keys, and each partition is stored on a separate node. Therefore, the first 3 rows of your pyspark dataframe are almost certainly stored on different nodes, and the entire dataframe will need to be loaded into memory in order to access certain rows. If your PySpark DataFrame is large, this could take a long time (and although I don't know how your PySpark DataFrame was created, I would encourage you to look into a way to remove the unneeded rows before the creation of the PySpark DataFrame).

You could try something like the [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70451815/remove-first-row-from-pyspark-dataframe) (but for the reasons stated above, this could take a long time due to `df.tail` and `df.count` requiring the entire df to be loaded into memory):

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame(df.tail(df.count()-4), schema=list(df.collect()[3]))

+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|real_column_name1|real_column_name2|real_column_name3|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
|               a1|               a2|               a3|
|               b1|               b2|               b3|
|               c1|               c2|               c3|
+-----------------+-----------------+-----------------+
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Appreciate it.

I keep getting "dataframe object has no attribute tail".

but the type(df) is indeed <class 'pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'>

Comment: what version of pyspark are you using? i'm using `v3.5.0` and the df.tail method was added in `3.0.0` according to the docs

Comment: I am running it on hdinsight on-demand cluster in Azure datafactory. It's version is 4.0..
spark is 2.4

Comment: @dragraichu I haven't used HDInsight, but are you able to upgrade the version of spark to at least 3.0.0?

Comment: Even I am not sure how to change the version, I am checking, will update here.

Comment: I am unable to change the version, will keep looking on ms docs, but any other suggestions ?

Comment: Hi Derek, I tried this way, let me know your thoughts:
After header is set, I tried this:

 `newDF = (DF.withColumn("uniqueId", monotonically_increasing_id())
      .withColumn("index",row_number().over(Window.orderBy(col("uniqueId"))))
         .filter("index > 4").drop("uniqueId", "index"))`

Comment: @dragraichu yeah that's a reasonable workaround!

Comment: @dragraichu to give our discussion a bit more visibility (and help anyone who has future questions similar to yours), feel free to add your comment as another answer and upvote/accept whichever answer helped you the most. thanks!

Comment: ok, I am adding my comment as an answer in continuation to your answer.

Answer (score 0):

As @Derek answered above, after trying out his answer, I was getting an error as "dataframe object has no attribute tail" but the type(df) is indeed <class pyspark.sql.dataframe.DataFrame'.

So what I tried is this. After header is set:

`newDF = (DF.withColumn("uniqueId", monotonically_increasing_id())       .withColumn("index",row_number().over(Window.orderBy(col("uniqueId"))))          .filter("index > 4").drop("uniqueId", "index"))`